How to use xrandr in systemd system session services?
I develop a program that use xrandr for getting information about current screen resolution and refresh rates. The program must run as a system service.
I wrote a simple service to test how xrandr would work in this way:
[Unit]
Description=xrandrsystemd

[Service]
ExecStart=xrandr

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and when I start it, xrandr failed with message Can't open display. I guess it is because system services start before X server so xrandr can't access to it to get information without DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environment variables that set after some user logs in to graphical session.
If I hardcoded these variables to .service file, xrandr works correctly.
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/<logged_user>/.Xauthority"

The problem is that solution suits only for <logged_user> on this machine, but I need more common solution. I tried to add something like XAUTHORITY=$(su - $USER -c "echo $HOME/.Xauthority") at .service file or replace xrandr call in ExecStart to shell script like DISPLAY=...; XAUTHORITY=...; xrandr, but it doesn't work.
Are there ideas how to get X server info from system session services?

I imagine you don’t want to debate this, but I have to ask — can’t your program run as an autostart X11 program rather than as a system service?

Nope, it must be a system service.

You don’t need X11 to determine the current modes on connected screens; you can use drm_info (in the drm-info package in Debian and derivatives, drm_info in Fedora and derivatives):
drm_info | grep -A1 MODE_ID

For scripting purposes, you’d be better off parsing the command’s JSON output (drm_info -j) — look for CRTCs with mode information, for example
drm_info -j|jq -r '.[].crtcs[].mode | select(has("name")) | "\(.hdisplay)x\(.vdisplay)@\(.vrefresh)"'

If you want to list all supported modes, you can decode the EDIDs found by the kernel itself:
for file in /sys/class/drm/*/edid; do
  text=$(tr -d '\0' <"$file")
  if [ -n "$text" ]; then
    edid-decode "$file"
  fi
done

edid-decode is commonly packaged in distributions (e.g. as the edid-decode package in Debian and derivatives, and Fedora and derivatives).

I've found a possible solution - you can use a XAuthority file generated by your OS desktop manager. For example, it would be /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 for LightDM and .service file would like that:
[Unit]
Description=xrandrsystemd

[Service]
ExecStart=xrandr
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/<logged_user>/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Other DMs are described here.
You can find such auth files in output of ps a | grep auth.
